# Java Date Filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a property 'dueDate' of type 'java.util.Date' stored in data-store say 
**Sat Mar 15 00:00:00 IST 2014**.
I have to list entities which have dueDate later than today (including today)
The following query fails to fetch today's dueDate entity.

```
      q.setFilter(FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL.of('dueDate', new Date()));
```

I am running this query today (15th March)
 How can I fix this? how can I compare only date and year part of whole date?

thanks
Ma

Comment: Using Calendar.getInstance(), set hour/minute/seconds to 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to construct a Date object for your filter:

```
long time = new Date().getTime();
Date date = new Date(time - time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: thanks for reply , the issue is resolved when I constructed Date object with a 'simpleDateFormatter' object.                                    Date d=new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(new Date()));